# Click Event Registered with jQuery Live in Google Map InfoWindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps, live, mouseclick-event, infowindow

I was using the technique described here [Click event in Google Map InfoWindow not caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217267/click-event-in-google-map-infowindow-not-caught) to dynamically add click event handlers to some of the content added to the Google Map InfoWindow.  Works great except in IE.

I have content with normal anchor tags and those links work just fine.

I have an anchor tag with a jQuery (live) click handler read the id to trigger some other action and it does nothing in IE.  Chrome/FF etc work just fine.  I've tried using a div and span with no change to the behavior.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**  This is with Google Maps v2 (I do know it is deprecated) and doesn't work in IE 7 or 8.  Haven't bothered with IE6 on this project.

**Edit:**  Here is a some sample code that repos the behavior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzr2EBOXUKnm_jVnk0OJI7xSosDVG8KKPE1-m51RBrvYughuyMxQ-i1QfUnH94QxWIa6N4U6MouMmBA" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#gmap{ height:450px;width:350px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var gmap;
    var sampleLatLon = new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
    var sampleIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Google maps setup
        $(window).unload(function () { GUnload(); });
        var gmap = new GMap2(document.getElementById("gmap"));
        gmap.setCenter(sampleLatLon, 13);
        gmap.setUIToDefault();

        // Marker and InfoWindow setup
        var marker = new GMarker(sampleLatLon, { icon: sampleIcon });
        var infoWindowMarkup = '<a id="infowindow-1" class="clickeventvialive">click me</a>';
        marker.bindInfoWindowHtml(infoWindowMarkup);
        gmap.addOverlay(marker);

        $('.clickeventvialive').live('click', function () {
            alert('Are you Internet Exploder??');
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="gmap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using Google Maps v3 or v2? Also - which versions of IE - 6/7/8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of solving that one with jquery another using old skool javascript onclick.

In the jQuery method binding the event AFTER the info window is shown and the  element created seems to solve the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzr2EBOXUKnm_jVnk0OJI7xSosDVG8KKPE1-m51RBrvYughuyMxQ-i1QfUnH94QxWIa6N4U6MouMmBA" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #gmap {
                height: 450px;
                width: 350px;
            }


        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var gmap;
            var sampleLatLon = new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
            var sampleIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);

            $(document).ready(function(){

                // Google maps setup
                $(window).unload(function(){
                    GUnload();
                });
                var gmap = new GMap2(document.getElementById("gmap"));
                gmap.setCenter(sampleLatLon, 13);
                gmap.setUIToDefault();

                // Marker and InfoWindow setup
                var marker = new GMarker(sampleLatLon, {
                    icon: sampleIcon
                });

                //marker.bindInfoWindowHtml(infoWindowMarkup);

                GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
                    var infoWindowMarkup = '<div class="container"><a id="infowindow-1" class="clickeventvialive">click me</a></div>';
                    gmap.openInfoWindowHtml(sampleLatLon, infoWindowMarkup, {
                        "onOpenFn": function(){
                         $(".clickeventvialive").bind("click", function (){alert("hello")});
                        }
                    });

                });



                gmap.addOverlay(marker);

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gmap">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

or the old skool method where you can simply add  onclick handler to to your link HTML:

```
var infoWindowMarkup = '<a id="infowindow-1" onclick=alert("Old Skool") class="clickeventvialive">click me</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I ended up going the intrusive javascript way and in-lining the onclick even in the markup.  I loose 50 point SO rep and tons of dev cred but it was late on a Friday and I needed a fix.  Later I'll look into the GEvent to redeem myself (if anything, just for myself).